# MS-Access Modal Form instead of message box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a modal form to appear instead of a message box. 
I want the user to have the option to overwrite a table or else append records onto a table.

So I have created a form with 3 buttons, Append, Overwrite and Cancel, each of these buttons have the relevant code behind them. However I am having issues with getting the form to appear and close.

I am using the following code to get the form to appear:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm ("frm_MessageBoxOptions")
```

This makes the form appear fine, however when I try add in any more option I get an error:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm ("frm_MessageBoxInventory", acPreview)
```

Compile error: Expected =

I'm not sure what is going wrong, and I am pretty new to VBA. I've been googling solutions but can't seem to get the code right.

I also want the 'cancel' button to close the modal form, but none of the following work foe me:

```
DoCmd.CloseForm "frm_MessageBoxOption"
Me.Close
```

Additionally, is there any tips or methods I can use to get the modal form to look similar to a message box?

Comment: No parentheses unless you want return values! So `DoCmd.OpenForm ("frm_MessageBoxInventory", acPreview)`. `DoCmd.OpenForm ("frm_MessageBoxOptions")` works because `("frm_MessageBoxOptions")` evaluates to `"frm_MessageBoxOptions"` (similar as `(5 + 2)` evaluates to `7`), but `("frm_MessageBoxInventory", acPreview)` evaluates to nothing at all

Comment: `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMessageBoxOption", acSaveNo`